# Proxy index gets converted to string

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-proxy

Trying out the new [Proxy objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), I am surprised that when a proxy is set the key is automatically converted to a string:

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

arr = new Proxy(arr, {
  get: (original, key) => {
    alert(typeof key);
    return original[key];
  }
});

arr[1];  // expected an alert with 'number'; got 'string' instead
```

There I would expect that `typeof key` would be `number`, since I am passing it a number. However, it gets converted to a string inside `Proxy` somehow and the actual alerted type is `string`. You can [see a small JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/franciscop/mu96714o/) that showcases the problem. `arr` is still an Array even after passing it through the proxy.

So, **how could I differentiate from passing a string and a number?** I could just regex it out as in `/\d+/.test(key)`, however it'd not differentiate between these situations and it just feels like a hack:

```
arr['1'];
arr[1];
```

Comment: The property name is converted to a string even before the value of the property access is determined, i.e. there is no way for a proxied object to know what the original value was. See the spec: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-property-accessors-runtime-semantics-evaluation

Comment: Coincidentally, native array won't differentiate between `arr['1']` and `arr[1]`, too, for the reason that is explained in the answer. So yes, `/^\d+$/` should be used. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/39802685/3731501 for the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Property keys can be only strings or symbols. If you're using something different, like a number, it always gets converted to a string first. Therefore, when using a Proxy you can't distinguish between these two operations:

```
arr['1'];
arr[1];
```

Both of them will trigger the Proxy get handler with `'1'` as the property key.

---

Also, the fact that you're using an array doesn't change anything―it works the same with arrays (which are special kind of objects) as it works with plain objects.

---

See also [The Object Type in the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-type).

Comment: Perfect, thank you. With your first sentence I also found more relevant info:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940424/valid-javascript-object-property-names#comment32771282_2940427 (and link to MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties ). So basically it's accessing the array itself which is converting it to an string, nothing to do with the Proxy.

Comment: It's worth noting that I solved it with a simple `if (key in lists) return lists[key];`, which will catch both generic array methods such as `.forEach()`, `.map()`, etc as well as said numberic indexes